Can openldap ignore the -z (size limit) parameter in ldapsearch
I have an issue with a client application performing an ldap search against my Ubuntu 22.04 openldap server.  As you can see in the wireshark trace, the client is specifying a sizelimit=1 for the search response, yet it's a wildcard query for the object.  Predictably, any more than one user account causes the search to fail with a sizelimit exceeded error.
The identical search works fine when the search size limit (ldapsearch -z 1 ...) is not used.
    LDAPMessage searchRequest(31) "ou=users,dc=xxxxxxxxxx,dc=com" singleLevel
        messageID: 31
        protocolOp: searchRequest (3)
            searchRequest
                baseObject: ou=users,dc=xxxxxxxxxx,dc=com
                scope: singleLevel (1)
                derefAliases: neverDerefAliases (0)
==>         sizeLimit: 1
                timeLimit: 0
                typesOnly: False
                Filter: (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(homeDirectory=*))
                    filter: and (0)
                        and: (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(homeDirectory=*))
                            and: 2 items
                                Filter: (objectClass=posixAccount)
                                    and item: equalityMatch (3)
                                        equalityMatch
                                            attributeDesc: objectClass
                                            assertionValue: posixAccount
                                Filter: (homeDirectory=*)
                                    and item: present (7)
                                        present: homeDirectory
                attributes: 1 item
                    AttributeDescription: homeDirectory

Question: I know I can specify server-side size search limits in openldap, but is there any way of explicitly ignoring the client-side size limit in the search request (if specified) and returning all results?  I have no control over the client app in order to remove size limits on the search request.
